# Object reference not set to an instance of an object #2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, findcontrol

I have got below error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Code-behind:

```
public partial class Edit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private TextBox updated_time;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updated_time = (TextBox)ABC_DV.FindControl("txt_updated_time");
        updated_time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

how could i solve this ?

**UPDATED**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="ABC_DV" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
        DefaultMode="Edit" DataKeyNames="TYPE_ID" DataSourceID="ABC_EDS">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type Id" SortExpression="TYPE_ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_type_id" Width="200" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TYPE_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TYPE_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TYPE_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>        
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Updated Time" SortExpression="UDPATED_TIME">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_updated_time" Width="200" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UDPATED_TIME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UDPATED_TIME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Labe2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UDPATED_TIME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>            
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Make sure that `ABC_DV` is properly instantiated and that `txt_updated_time` exists in `ABC_DV` so the `FindControl` call doesn't return null.

Comment: At what level? Post your markup or relevant building code, `FindControl` is not recursive.

Comment: Seems like `(TextBox)ABC_DV.FindControl("txt_updated_time");` is returning null, which means `ABC_DV.FindControl()` cannot find `txt_updated_time`. Can you upload the aspx code of ABC_DV?

Comment: Please post the markup un aspx

Comment: @QuintinRobinson i have added aspx markup to the post

Comment: @CarlosLande I have added aspx markup to the post

Comment: i have added aspx markup to the post

Comment: @Bishan okay you need to take into consideration the mode the `DetailsView` is in when attempting to access a control, it *will not* exist in the hierarchy if it isn't in the edit mode causing the `Page_Load` to explode when it is called without the `DetailsView` in edit mode. Add some checks to your code to properly handle the control state.

Comment: Your textbox does have the correct ID, so that's not the issue. The only thing I can think of is that the control doesn't exist at the time `ABC_DV.FindControl` is being executed, like what others suggested.

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you need to take into consideration the mode the `DetailsView` is in when attempting to access a control, it will not exist in the hierarchy if it isn't in the edit mode causing the `Page_Load` to explode when it is called without the `DetailsView` in edit mode. Add some checks to your code to properly handle the control state.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ABC_DV.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit) {
      updated_time = (TextBox)ABC_DV.FindControl("txt_updated_time");
      if(null != updated_time)
        updated_time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox updated_time = ABC_DV.FindControl("txt_updated_time") as TextBox;
if (updated_time  != null)
{
    updated_time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time you hit the `Page_Load` method your controls should have been reconstructed and added back into the page. The fact that you are getting an error at that point indicates that particular control doesn't exist - at least not with the ID that you've specified.

Try moving the code into your `PreRender()` - this is the method that is executed just before the page is rendered to the response stream, if you have added dynamic controls or messed with the IDs of controls then that should have happened well before this stage.